# Enabled Revisions to existing custom post type not working Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

I am trying to enable revisions for an existing custom post type. As the post type was already created about 2 years ago so where the post type was register I added `revisions` to the `supports` array.

Earlier my code was like:

```
   $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',      
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Products',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' =>  'No Prducsts Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
  $supports = array(
    'title',
    'custom-fields',
    'editor',
    'thumbnail'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => $supports 
  ); 
  register_post_type('products', $args);
```

And now it looks like:

```
   $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',      
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Products',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' =>  'No Prducsts Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
  $supports = array(
    'title',
    'custom-fields',
    'editor',
    'thumbnail',
    'revisions'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => $supports 
  ); 
  register_post_type('products', $args);
```

This code didn't enable revisions in the custom post type.

Then I found another code which I added to my theme's function.php:

```
function add_revisions_custom_post()
{
    add_post_type_support( 'products', 'revisions' );
}
add_action('init','add_revisions_custom_post');
```

This one is also not working.

Can anyone suggest me how I can enable revisions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is my wp-config.php file.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');

define('DB_NAME', 'MYDBNAME');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'MYDBUSER');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MYDBPASSWORD');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'c7ypbekexsfbt4wiucppwewene93cbtcfhf6xgpggepycabhildsoyqpre5iv3wi');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'ujjxufvylpndsj0qeuwa90gxawj3cgaqnyusrdbmujmb08r37pnyreorpcyxqouu');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'vwlhlmenthgrq9g5jcocihz4ndldhrpegmcp6qyb3rfmjvxjejbacv1zharaexlp');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'qhnyqgmqckh3ylasveugagqlvifiuqajl6s9e7ulfrxepdxh2mewr8qhdinua8o2');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'rlb723gcatjvkfrd3jscmvdjio3kx9apm5yie9e4ibxktnnlukvgfpgbdsohrns9');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'pllenyye8zbtml91hekptc2clqr7bhvhlriecz5qozexfhiqptmcvxrlehj44c16');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '9lyqc6qod0zdgyh6esp7bsxmpmuyp3h64m62pcnwxyefejh6tjykm7tpxhecg3xy');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'ob0bq3fye46rubbgu5flycjuai4ygxqgxho8bb1k8t81mwhghcbkysrgxrjzx0fu');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress.  A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define ('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Don't worry, you are not alone with this. The revision on your site will work for NEW posts on that post type. It wont work for EXISTING posts in that post type, no matter how many edits you make to it.

Why this is the case, I am still trying to figure out myself and will let you know once I do.

Comment: OK - plain simple. Please try to save the SAME post at least TWICE and each time make sure to actually EDIT something in the post. That will then trigger the revision. It is expected, because if you enable revision on a CPT that has no revisions yet, editing the post the FIRST time after enabling revision has NO revision to fallback to, thus, nothing can be shown. Only the SECOND time you edit it, it will have a revision to fallback to, and thus, will display it. I am almost 100% sure this is the issue you faced here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cap_type = 'post';
$plural = 'Products';
$single = 'Product';
$cpt_name = 'products';

$opts['supports'] = array( 'products', 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'revisions' );
$opts['can_export'] = TRUE;
$opts['capability_type'] = $cap_type;
$opts['description'] = '';
$opts['exclude_from_search'] = FALSE;
$opts['has_archive'] = TRUE;
$opts['hierarchical'] = TRUE;
$opts['map_meta_cap'] = TRUE;
$opts['menu_icon'] = 'dashicons-products';
$opts['menu_position'] = 2;
$opts['public'] = TRUE;
$opts['publicly_queryable'] = TRUE;
$opts['query_var'] = TRUE;
$opts['register_meta_box_cb'] = '';
$opts['rewrite'] = array('slug'=>'products', 'with_front'=>false);
$opts['show_in_admin_bar'] = TRUE;
$opts['show_in_menu'] = TRUE;
$opts['show_in_nav_menu'] = TRUE;

$opts['labels']['add_new'] = esc_html__( "Add New", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['add_new_item'] = esc_html__( "Add New {$single}", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['all_items'] = esc_html__( "All {$plural}", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['edit_item'] = esc_html__( "Edit {$single}" , 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['menu_name'] = esc_html__( $plural, 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['name'] = esc_html__( $plural, 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['name_admin_bar'] = esc_html__( $single, 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['new_item'] = esc_html__( "New {$single}", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['not_found'] = esc_html__( "No {$single} found", 'wisdom');
$opts['labels']['not_found_in_trash'] = esc_html__( "Not found {$plural} in Trash", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['parent_item_colon'] = esc_html__( "Parent {$plural} :", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['search_items'] = esc_html__( "Search {$plural}", 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['singular_name'] = esc_html__( $single, 'wisdom' );
$opts['labels']['view_item'] = esc_html__( "View {$single}", 'wisdom' );
register_post_type( strtolower( $cpt_name ), $opts );
```

try this

Comment: :( It's not working..

Comment: are you sure you don't have revisions turned off? be sure this does not exist in wp-config.php: define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);

Comment: yes, I did check this. and it's not in my wp-config.php

Comment: Have you check on a page/post edit panel? click on "Screen Options" in the top right and look for a "Revisions" checkbox and make sure it is active

Comment: Yes, I checked that too. In screen options, there is no option to show revisions. I just want to confirm one thing that if I added the revisions to the supports array of custom post type then will it affect the data which is already added to the posts?

Comment: What i found is that i have a staging domain but with latest wp version i.e. 4.9.8 and the live site have version 4.7.11. When i go to default post type on live site having older version i can see the revisions there for that but the site with latest wp version don't show revisions.

Comment: Still the same :(. Not showing revisions. Is that an issue with wp version?

Comment: I don't know dude, but on my website there is no issue

Comment: i think your code is right, maybe issue with your config. sorry for my english

Comment: I update my post with wp-config.php file. Have a look at it

Comment: define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false); change to define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', true);

Comment: I am not using `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);` in my config file but still i added `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', true);` to my file. Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the basics are all in place:

- `register_post_type` includes `'revisions'` in the `supports` args array
- `WP_POST_REVISIONS` is either not defined or set to true in wp-config.php
- open Screen Options and make sure "Revisions" is checked. (Though I think this only controls the big meta box, and the small "revisions" link should appear below "visibility" no matter how this is set)

Next, make sure you actually have two versions of the post you're trying to test.

- Create a new test post of your CPT with any content
- Make a change/edit to the content and Update (don't just press Update - make sure to actually change something)

You should now see revisions available and be able to revert to old versions.

Comment: h/t @BedaSchmid and OP for working most of this out in the comments already. Just wanted to put a clear summary here in the form of an answer.